# What FileMode if I want to select a file with FileStream and make a copy?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

lets say there is a Function

```
public void UploadSomewhere(FileStream fs)
```

If I use FileStream Its not enough to point to the file path, I need also to select the `FileMode` and Im not sure what is the correct FileMode if you are just copy/moving the file. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do if the target file already exists?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with the file? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you want to use FileStream you can simply use **Open** for the source file.

e.g.,

```
var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

For the *target* file you have to decide what happens if it exists:

**Create** will let you overwrite an existing file if you've got the **Write** permission.

**CreateNew** will throw if the file exists.  Again, you'd need the **Write** permission.

But, as others have written, you could skip the FileStream completely and use the File commands.

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're just **coping/moving** file, and you know already path (as much as I understand from the question), you do not need `FieStream` at all. It's enough to use `File.Move` or `File.Copy` functions.

Comment: If he must stream the data over network sockets (FTP), he can't use `File` methods.

Comment: @Scoregraphic: if he is going to write it's own implementation of FTP transfer, he should make use of FtpWebRequest, and not FileStream.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

If you only need to read the file, I suggest `FileMode.Open`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a file using FileStream the example below should point you to the right way.

```
using (FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream("c:\\pathToSourceFile", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (FileStream destFile = new FileStream("c:\\pathToDestinationFile", FileMode.Create))
    {
        int bufferSize = 65536;
        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

        while ((bytesRead = sourceFile.Read(bytes, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            destFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are copying the file `FileMode.Open` and `FileAccess.Read`.

If you want to share access to the file during this process, specify the `FileShare` option as well.

Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare) for more information.